# Data missing in ASP post to MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post

I have an ASP page:

```
<%
sData = "VARIABLE=SOMEDATAHERE"
oHttpRequest.Open "POST", "http://????/AAA/BBB", False
oHttpRequest.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
oHttpRequest.Send sData

oPostResponse = oHttpRequest.ResponseText

Response.Write oPostResponse
%>
```

I am posting this to an MVC site:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BBB(string PORTAL)
{
}
```

In my BBB function I am unable to get to SOMEDATAHERE.

I have tried:

```
Request.Form["VARIABLE"]
Request.ServerVariables["VARIABLE"]
```

Ive tried reading the raw stream using the code below but thats blank too..
I am not sure what else I can try?

```
        System.IO.Stream str; String strmContents;
        Int32 counter, strLen, strRead;
        // Create a Stream object.
        str = Request.InputStream;
        // Find number of bytes in stream.
        strLen = Convert.ToInt32(str.Length);
        // Create a byte array.
        byte[] strArr = new byte[strLen];
        // Read stream into byte array.
        strRead = str.Read(strArr, 0, strLen);

        // Convert byte array to a text string.
        strmContents = "";
        for (counter = 0; counter < strLen; counter++)
        {
            strmContents = strmContents + strArr[counter].ToString();
        }
```

Comment: I've never tried from a asp page to mvc controller, but you should get your value in the "PORTAL" parameter. If you PORTAL parameter is empty I guess is because you`re not sending it correctly.

Comment: i am definitely sending it because when i send it to a big standard classic .ASP page I do see it.its almost as if something somewhere is ripping it out...